# How to append numpy arrays to txt file

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library

There are a list of image files I want to convert to numpy arrays and append them to a txt file, each array line after line. This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os

data = os.listdir("inputs")
print(len(data))

with open('np_arrays.txt', 'a+') as file:
    for dt in data:
        img = Image.open("inputs\\" + dt)
        np_img = np.array(img)
        file.write(np_img)
        file.write('\n')
```

but `file.write()` requires a string and does not accept a numpy ndarray. How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you want this text to look like?  An array made from a 'image' probably will be something large and multidimensional like (640,400,3).  That won't make a useable text, especially not one line. Also how do you expect to use this file, that is, reload those "images"?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense as it stands. It is highly inefficient to write images as text - there is a reason why we have JPEGs and PNGs. Can you explain further please? My camera saves 40MB files, if it wrote them as text, they would take 20x the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy also allows you to save directly to `.txt` files with `np.savetxt`.
I'm still not entirely sure what format you want your text file to be in but a solution might be something like:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os

data = os.listdir("inputs")
print(len(data))

shape = ( len(data), .., .., ) # input the desired shape

np_imgs = np.empty(shape)

for i, dt in enumerate(data):
    img = Image.open("inputs\\" + dt)
    np_imgs[i] = np.array(img) # a caveat here is that all images should be of the exact same shape, to fit nicely in a numpy array

np.savetxt('np_arrays.txt', np_imgs)
```

Note that `np.savetxt()` has a lot of parameters that allow you to finetune the outputted txt file.

Comment: `shape = ( len(data), .., .., )` this is throwing an error. What are those 2 ellipses for?

Comment: Those are fr you to fill in the shape of `np.array(img)`. As I mentioned this will work only if all your img files have the same shape as numpy arrays.

Comment: What's the order?

Comment: It's the basic order of array dimensions numpy works with. Go have a look how `np.array().shape` works.

Answer (score 0):

The `write()` function only allows strings as its input. Try using [`numpy.array2string`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html).

Comment: Is there a way to reverse `numpy.array2string` to something like `numpy.string2array`?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to reverse the operation using [`numpy.fromstring()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html). Just make sure you account for the square brackets that `numpy.array2string` adds by default. For example, if you have `test = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])` and `testString = np.array2string(test)`, the operation to convert back to a numpy array would be `np.fromstring(testString[1:-1], dtype='int', sep = " ")`.

Comment: The output looks like this: `[[[111  60   0]
 [116  65   0]
 [122  69   0]
 ...
 [ 97  47   0]
 [ 99  47   0]
 [100  49   0]]
[[111  61   0]
 [118  65   0]
 [122  69   0]` The ellipsis suggest that the array is truncated. Is there a way to output the entire thing?

Comment: As I guessed the array is 3d (n,m,3).  While it is possible to turn off that ellipsis, parsing such a text is still going to be a pain.  Do you really need/want to write a text file like this?  The common text file format is `csv`, which is good for 2d tables, one array/table per file.

Comment: Can we turn off the ellipsis?